# Hide menu when click outside the area - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I create button in Bootstrap when i click is show info window. 
I want when info window it is shown, if i click outside the area of info then info window  will hide and icons in button change too

demo

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLeRYd

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-info-icons').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-info]');
    var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
    sideslider.click(function (event) {
        $(sel).toggleClass('in');
    });
});
```

I found a solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#navbar-info-panel");
        var container1 = $("#nav-info-icons");
        var opened = $("#nav-info-icons").hasClass("open");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && !container1.is(e.target) && container1.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            if (opened) {
                $("button.navbar-toggle-info").click();
                $("#nav-info-icons").removeClass("open");
            }
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an answer to your question rather than an edit

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
$('body,html').on('click', function() {
   $('#nav-info-icons').removeClass('open'); // Hide the nav
   $(sel).removeClass('in'); // Hide for collapse
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Update the JS with the below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-info]');
    var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');

    sideslider.click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();  //Stop even bubbling to parent
        $(sel).toggleClass('in');
        $('#nav-info-icons').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('#nav-info-icons').click(function () {
        event.stopPropagation(); //Stop even bubbling to parent
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(sel).toggleClass('in');
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is($('#nav-info-icons span'))) return; //Don't execute onclick

        if($('#nav-info-icons').attr("class") === "open") //Check for class - open, then hide info panel
        {
            $('#nav-info-icons').removeClass('open');
            $('#navbar-info-panel').addClass('in');
        }
    })
});
```